# backendless easy facebook login: fetching first name

Tags: ios, swift, backendless

I'm trying to login to facebook using backendless easyLogin* method in Swift and to fetch user's facebook name to display further. I'm able to login successfully but can't get the name.

The code is as the following (`"first_name"` is facebooks graph field to map, `"displayName"` is backendless custom user field):

```
let backendless = Backendless.sharedInstance();

backendless.userService.easyLoginWithFacebookFieldsMapping(

    ["email":"email", "first_name":"displayName"], permissions: ["email", "public_profile"],

    response: {(result : NSNumber!) -> () in

    print ("Result: \(result)")

},

error: { (fault : Fault!) -> () in

    print("Server reported an error: \(fault)")

})
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what was the exact problem but the following worked for me:

1. I've removed previously created facebook user from backendless user table
2. Tried to login using the following code snippet:

> ```
> func easyFacebookLogin() {
>     let fieldsMapping = [
>     "name" : "name",
>     "first_name": "first_name",
>     "last_name" : "last_name",
>     "email": "email"]
>     backendless.userService.easyLoginWithFacebookFieldsMapping(
>     fieldsMapping,
>     permissions: ["email"],
>     response: {(result : NSNumber!) -> () in
>     print ("Result: \(result)")
>     },
>     error: { (fault : Fault!) -> () in
>     print("Server reported an error: \(fault)")
>     })
> }
> ```

3. Everything worked as expected - name was fetched and mapped